# HP's UFT REST Authentication Process

Tags: soapui, hp-uft

I need assistance on following:

Using the HP's UFT or SoAPUI

- Go to website (GET)
- Sign in with authorization code and username/pwd (POST)
- system generates a bearer token
- Now go ahead and to other activities with this token (involves PUT) here.

Regards

Comment: What are you asking about ?

Comment: I do not know where to use authorization key in UFT (that is API key at header). Cant figure out

Answer (score 0):

In case you were asking how to insert the HTTP header 'Authorization' into your request:

For UFT:

1 - select your resquest
2 - Properties / Event / BeforeApplyProtocolSettings / New Handler
3 - 
        public void StServiceCallActivity4_OnBeforeApplyProtocolSettings(object sender, HP.ST.Ext.WebServicesActivities.Models.StChannelsBindingStack args)
        {
            this.StServiceCallActivity4.HttpRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization","Basic d29tZXVzZXI6c29tZXBhc3M=");
        }

// Warning StServiceCallActivity4 have to match the Service activity call you are modifying with this event.
4 - Reproduce for each request (I did not find a better solution for this unfortunatly)

Bonus: From there you can always get the user / password from input parameter and encode the String in the method.

For Soap UI:

1 - Open your request
2 - On the bottom tab called 'Header': Add a Header called 'Authorization' with the value 'Basic d29tZXVzZXI6c29tZXBhc3M='

Hope it's what you need

Comment: That works for SOAP WebServices. I am not seeing BeforeApplyProtocolSettings for REST

Comment: Hum, here is something that could help you:
http://www.sqaforums.com/forums/hp-unified-functional-testing-uft-mercury-quicktest-pro-qtp/148817-web-services-cant-quite-get-there.html